# Wiki editor for gnome desktop

Tags: linux, editor, wiki, gnome

Is there any wiki editor for linux desktop where I can use wiki syntax and print a rendered page ? currently I am using gnome and gedit

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use zim wiki check out http://zim-wiki.org/

Comment: Before posting this, I had tried with Zim, but I have not got it. now I have revisited Zim, and it is amazing! I love it, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Libre office extention called libreoffice-wiki-publisher
It wont allow wiki syntax, but does give you a rendered page

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-wiki-publisher
```

Wiki Publisher: the Wiki Publisher extension lets you create Wiki articles on MediaWiki servers without having to know MediaWiki markup language. You can publish new and existing documents to a wiki page, transparently with Writer. Wiki Publisher supports essential text attributes such as headings, hyperlinks and lists, as well as simple tables. Images are also supported if already uploaded to the wiki site. Automatic images uploading is not currently supported. This is the perfect extension if you want to make existing documentations and specifications available on MediaWiki servers. Just load the document and invoke the Extension via the "Send – MediaWiki Server" command. A dialog box guides you through the publication process.

Source http://www.libreoffice.org/features/extensions/

Comment: I know the wiki syntax, I and don't need to publish it anywhere else, just want to use/enjoy wiki's easiness on Desktop, especially for document printing

Comment: Ok sorry, misread the question. so you are looking for a text editor that will use the wiki syntax and render?

Comment: nasir did you try zim wiki